# Run Javascript once on homepage and remember

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal that shows on page load. However, I want it to not show again when the user visits this page again. It can load again if the browser is closed(ends the browsing session on the website). As of right now, modal will load every time I'm in or revisit index page..

> index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('show');
 });
</script>

 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"    aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
   <div class="modal-content">
    ...
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can use window.sessionstorage

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya, `sessionStorage` is more specific considering the `use-case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Write your script as

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).load(function(){ 
        if(!sessionStorage.visited) 
        {
           sessionStorage.visited = true;
           $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionStorage api for exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

try the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($.cookie('is_shown') == null || $.cookie('is_shown') == ""){
            $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('show');
            $.cookie('is_shown', 'yes');
            //$.cookie("is_shown", '1');
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can also do by sessionStorage see Code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('is_shown') !== 'true') {

            $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('show');
            sessionStorage.setItem('is_shown','true');

        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage['has_visited'] = true